# How can I find out why a curl connection to a server can take more than 30 seconds?

Tags: curl

There is a VPS server (ubuntu) and an ip camera with a white address. The server makes requests to the camera every 10 minutes to check for new videos. One check includes 6 requests (check ip availability, get token, set parameters, received data, stop token, delete token). The curl request looks like this:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, [CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'admin:admin', 
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 500,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH=>CURLAUTH_ANY
]);
```

Today for some unknown reason I started getting the error Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds. The error occurs at any of the 6 steps. For the sake of an experiment I ran a loop with 100 such queries. Forty-nine of them had errors.

I increased CONNECTTIMEOUT to 30, but it had no effect. I got error Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds.

The linux tag is because I assume the problem is on the server side, since if I perform the same requests from my home PC, there are 0 errors per 100 requests. The camera is not on the same local network on the PC. HOWEVER, if I turn on the VPN on my home PC from my server ip, the same errors occur. So there is obviously something wrong with the server.

Rostelecom (the camera provider) says that it's not their fault and it's my problem.

This is what tcpdump returns https://pastebin.com/QGsEJDLw I ran 10 curl queries on the muzzle. Of those, 2 had an error (more than 10 seconds to process)

Can you tell me how I can figure out the reason for the long connection?

Comment: Try running it via `strace` ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov я запустил скрипт и выполнил вот эту команду: `strace -f -e trace=network -p 508223 2>&1 | grep sin_addr` Начали появляться однотипные строки. В момент зависания они дублировались. Вот кусок: https://pastebin.com/07dmeYxP . 3-4 строка и 25-26 - это как раз момент ожидания. Извините, если я вас неправильно понял.

Comment: The `connect()` call seemingly fails or times out - no idea why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277970/what-are-possible-reason-for-socket-error-einprogress-in-solaris

Comment: Next step could be using wireshark to trace the network packets.